# Making an iphone webview go to a different webaddress when only the prefix is in the address bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

im curently working on a school project and my iphone app has been rejected twice and I know why. the solution to my problem though is tough. here i have the .m file from my project and I have a web based app. right now, if there is only http:// in the address bar, it displays an error that says the url's host is not found because it is only http:// and my app was rejected for that. what I want it to do is when only http:// is in the address bar, to make it go to a different web site. PLEASE HELP!! Plus I'm on iOS 6

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction)press {

    label.hidden = 0;
    addressBar.hidden = 0;
    browserPlace.hidden = 1;
    button.hidden = 1;
    button2.hidden = 0;

}
-(IBAction)press2
{
    label.hidden = 1;
    addressBar.hidden = 1;
    browserPlace.hidden = 0;
    button.hidden = 0;
    button2.hidden = 1;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    label.hidden = 1;
    addressBar.hidden = 1;
    browserPlace.hidden = 0;
    button.hidden = 0;
    button2.hidden = 1;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    addressBar.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"history"];




    [self searchBarSearchButtonClicked:addressBar];

}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [browserPlace loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self parseUrl:addressBar.text]]]];

}

-(NSString*) parseUrl: (NSString*) url
{
    if ([url hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [url hasPrefix:@"https://"]) 
        return url;
    else
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", url];



}




-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:addressBar.text forKey:@"history"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    label2.hidden = 0;

}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    label2.hidden = 1;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    label2.hidden = 1;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[error description] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];


}

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Your app will be rejected if webview is the only feature in your app.

Comment: Web view is not the only feature, this is only 1 view controller out of 4 and this one is partially a webview that is programmable by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `parseUrl:` method. Check to see if the URL is just "http://":

```
- (NSString *)parseUrl:(NSString *)url {
    if (url.length == 0 || [url isEqualToString:@"http://"]) {
        return @"http://www.someplacecool.com"; // put your desired URL here
    } else if ([url hasPrefix:@"http://"] || [url hasPrefix:@"https://"]) {
        return url;
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", url];
    }
}
```

You should also add other error checking in case the user enters any other invalid URLs.

Comment: I tried this method but every time even when I delete the app from the simulator I get this error message {2013-02-21 07:28:00.408 Avidhelper[12180:11903] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x75926c0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://http//(null), NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://http//(null), NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x758e7f0 "The requested URL was not found on this server."} How do I fix this?

Comment: That error indicates that you are trying to create a file URL from the URL string. Do you call `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:xxx]` in your code? Replace that with `[NSURL URLWithString:xxx]`.

Comment: I already use [NSURL URLWithString:[self parseUrl:addressBar.text]

Comment: I found it out. I noticed that the address bar is blank then I typed in just http:// then it took me the URL I wanted. Is there any way to make it where it will go to my URL if the address bar has either http:// or if its just blank?

Comment: @goofballcent See my updated answer (I changed the 1st `if` statement). This change is an example of what I mentioned in the sentence after my code.

Comment: There are many other cases you need to handle. What if the user just types a space? What if the user types just `http:`? There are many possible errors. You need to better handle errors from the web view.

Comment: My app is not based around the Address bar. the user should only need to use it once in the settings view. If you think I still need to code for other instances, could you tell me what? I'm very new to iOS Development.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

You can check the [request URL] and also its scheme.

Try to redirect the URL to different one in this method and return the respective BOOL value (YES/NO).